# Always start a new activity when phone is rotated

Tags: android

I added the following code to my manfest file thinking it will disable android from creating a new process when the device (2.2) is rotated, but it did not work

```
            <activity android:name=".cYesNoDisplay"  android:label="Your Answer">   
                android:configChanges="orientation"   
                android:configChanges="ScreenSize"        
    </activity>
```

I thought by decaling orientation and screen size a new activity would not be created?

Comment: you'll need to put the ">" of your activity declaration after the two configChanges lines that you've added. Those are properties of the activity itslef, not children of it that belong inside like you've done.

Comment: Why don't you just add an orientation layout, it will load that instead but use the same Activity and assuming some info you want was saved in the Bundle, it can be reused. But I don't believe anything extra needs added. Just leave it as is, with the changed layout orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also go into the activity .cYesNoDisplay and override the method onConfigurationChanged()? You don't need to implement anything in there, just override it should prevent the activity from being recreated when rotation changes.